# Image.FromFile with a username password. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok we need to load a file on the network, (Files are stored seperatly from the webserver).

Is there anyways we can specify a network userid a password when calling the function below?

Image.FromFile("\IPADDRESSHERE\GroupPictures\");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx) on impersonation in MSDN. See also [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2004/09/01/224064.aspx) about possible security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Open it using a file stream, and use Image.FromStream intsead.